# Unclear about Java

Tags: java

This maybe a stupid question. I am still getting learn and understand java. I have a concern that is getting me confused. I have a text document that has about 50 lines of info.

My concern is that I am trying to retrieve information on certain names and calculate the values next to their names as a total. Meaning if the doc is about baseball teams and their averages. I would like to calculate only those teams that belong to a certain division.

I have this code that helps me to calculate all.

```
public int totalAverage( ) {
    int total = 0;
    for ( int i = 0; i < teamArray.length; i++ ) {
        total += teamArray[i].getAverages( );
    }
    return total;
}
```

Comment: So what's the problem? In what format is your text file? Help us help you.

Comment: Your question is not really making much sense. In fact, there is no question there at all. Please put some relevant details there.

Answer (score 2):

Use a conditional statement (like the [`if`-statement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/if.html)) to check whether certain criteria are met. For example add a `division` parameter to the method, so you can check the total average of the division:

```
public int totalAverage(String division) {
    int total = 0;
    for ( int i = 0; i < teamArray.length; i++ ) {
        if(division.equals(teamArray[i].getDivision()) {
            // Team belongs to division, so increase total
            total += teamArray[i].getAverages( );
        }
    }
    return total;
}
```